# IIS IP & Domain Restrictions Block Everything

Tags: iis

I have IIS 10 running in Windows Server 2016. Installed the IP & Domain Restriction.
Setup Allow list for local IP 192.168.10.0/24
And set the feature setting Allow unspecified clients to Deny, action type = forbidden.
But it does not work. I can not open the website from anywhere including from local where my computer IP is 192.168.10.100.

Set the feature setting Allow unspecified clients to Allow. But now can open from everywhere. Anyone got a solution?

Comment: This link should help you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831785(v=ws.11)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831785(v=ws.11)).

Comment: Is your web server behind a firewall, Proxy or some other device where NAT is taking place? If so it could be that the IP & Domain restrictions feature is seeing the LAN IP address of the firewall, and not the clients actual IP. Try enabling the Proxy Mode in Feature Settings